# Where does Google Play Store put downloaded apps?

Tags: google-play-store, installation

I want to know where Google Play stores downloaded **.apk** files. I've heard that Google Play doesn't send you an `.apk` file and installation is completely online. Is it true?

Comment: Android saves **.apk** files in system folder, installs the package and deletes the file. Not sure about what I have said, but I saw it happen with file explorer that was capable to open system folders and partitions.

Comment: Nope, installed apps from the play store (.apk) aren't stored in the system folder. The file is also not deleted and stays in the /data folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.apk` files are downloaded and stored in subfolders under a location on your device called `/data`.

By default, you do not have permissions to read from that location. In order to read/write in that location, you will need to root your device.

Comment: For readers: the sub-folder is usually `/data/app` but don't forget `/data/app-private` and `/mnt/asec`.

Answer (score 0):

For now, Google sends you APK file and once it is finished downloading it installs it.

Seems the location of temp files is likely to change from time to time and can vary based on OS, as well as what you're downloading. I'm Presently, using MIUI 8.5.3

Downloads from Google Play Store go into different location for New and Existing apps.

**New apps** (as in you don't have previous version), go into: 
Folder: /data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/cache
Filename is:

- While it's downloading: download.bin.midownload (mostl likely
  OS-specific name)
- Once complete: download.apk (file
  is deleted some time after the download, usually not immediately after)

**Updates to Existing apps** 
Folder: /sdcard/Android/data/com.android.vending/files
Filename is:

- While it's downloading: #######.midownload (extension is likely OS-specific as well)
- Once complete: ??

Also, the following folder is created when you download new app or an update to existing one (## are numbers): /data/app/vmdl#####.tmp
It's empty during the downloading.